# tabs and page reloading

Tags: javascript, html, http, web

How do you make a page seem like it's tabbed when you are actually reloading the page? ie. avoid a flicker when re-rendering the page?

It seems like that's what twitter does for the tabbed view of its "followers, following, etc"

https://twitter.com/#!/google/following

The page reloads on each tab - but it looks like only the center content is changing - the rest of the page doesn't 'flicker' even though it reloads.

Edit:

I don't think what they are doing is AJAX - the entire page is actually reloaded, though the end result seems like ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually reloading the whole page, just retrieving the new content with AJAX to be placed in that area and then displaying it... it's dynamic AJAX content http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

Comment: nope - that's what it looks like is happening on the twitter page. but then i realized it's actually reloading the whole page - but it looks ajaxy.